# how to xpack security reset in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**`I want to reset the ID and password of elasticsearch and kibana.`**

I tried to reset it, but an error occurred as below.

```
ubuntu@elk:/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin$ sudo ./elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

**`error occured`**

```
Connection failure to: http://10.0.10.4:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty failed: Connection refused

ERROR: Failed to connect to elasticsearch at http://10.0.10.4:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty. Is the URL correct and elasticsearch running?
```

`my elasticsearch.yml file`

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.type: single-node
```

`my kibana.yml file`

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: "dlswp12"
#xpack.security.encryptionKey: "something_at_least_32_characters"
#xpack.security.sessionTimeout: 600000
#xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

> **how to xpack security(id & password) reset in elasticsearch?**